# cannot determine the cause of these test errors, debugger isnt functioning here, nor can i figure out how to resolve this

Tags: java, unit-testing, compiler-errors

the task here is to create a file, create a object called Student that takes a name, age gpa. the file is filled with lines that look roughly like this name=Jane Robinson,age=19,gpa=3.81 while reading each line I am to split the "," and the "=" and then check each index of array for "name", "age", "gpa" if one of those are found, to then substring(startpostion, rest of string); and save that as a variable, call the Student setters for each variable and set them, then load the newly set up Student objects into a ArrayList called result, that I may then return it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

/**
 * 
 *
 *
 *
 */
public class StudentReader {
   
  public static Student[] readFromTextFile(String fileName) {
  ArrayList<Student> result = new ArrayList<Student>();
   String name =" ";
   int age = 0;
   double gpa = 0.0;
   String fill;
   
   File f = new File(fileName);
   Scanner n = null;
   try
   {
       n = new Scanner(f);
   }
  catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
   {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   
   while (n.hasNextLine())
   {
     fill = n.nextLine();
     Student g =  new Student(name , age, gpa);
     String[] string1 = fill.split(",");
     
     String[] string2;
     for (int i = 0; i < string1.length; ++i)
     {
       
       string2 = string1[i].split("=");
      if (string2[i].substring(0,4).equals("name"))
        {
      name = string2[i].substring(4,string2[i].length());
        }
      if(string2[i].substring(0,3).equals("age"))
        {
      age = Integer.parseInt(string2[i].substring(3,string2[i].length()));
        }
      if(string2[i].substring(0,3).equals("gpa"))
        {
      gpa = Double.parseDouble(string2[i].substring(3,string2[i].length()));
        }
        
     }
   } 
    return result.toArray(new Student[0]);
  }
}
```

errors here:

```
ERROR IN YOUR CODE - testRead10Lines(StudentReaderTest):
     begin 0, end 4, length 2
     java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
          at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3116)
          at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1885)
          at StudentReader.readFromTextFile(StudentReader.java:43)
          at StudentReaderTest.testRead10Lines(StudentReaderTest.java:104)

2. ERROR IN YOUR CODE - testReadSingleLine(StudentReaderTest):
     begin 0, end 4, length 2
     java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
          at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3116)
          at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1885)
          at StudentReader.readFromTextFile(StudentReader.java:43)
          at StudentReaderTest.testReadSingleLine(StudentReaderTest.java:84)

3. ERROR IN YOUR CODE - testFileNotExist(StudentReaderTest):
     java.lang.NullPointerException
          at StudentReader.readFromTextFile(StudentReader.java:32)
          at StudentReaderTest.testFileNotExist(StudentReaderTest.java:113)
```

like I said in the question for some reason my debugger wont show me the cause here and I cant identify why the length of each object is only 2, I don't have any other information to give here as I have the whole task listed in the top. but can anyone tell me why I'm running these index out of bounds errors

Comment: The error is from `reafFromTextFile`. You can see stack trace as it indicates the line of error.

Answer (score 1):

It's the substring that's causing the issue.

It should be:

```
  if (string2[i].substring(0,3).equals("name"))
    {
  name = string2[i].substring(3,string2[i].length());
    }
  if(string2[i].substring(0,2).equals("age"))
    {
  age = Integer.parseInt(string2[i].substring(2,string2[i].length()));
    }
  if(string2[i].substring(0,2).equals("gpa"))
    {
  gpa = Double.parseDouble(string2[i].substring(2,string2[i].length()));
    }
```